# Abusing domain driven design

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

How can people abuse of Domain Driven Design ? too much too little information in the domain, what would you consider an abuse? In your design experience did you run into any situation that you considered that the design is just too much ?

-Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abusing DDD is using DDD to build each and every system. Both soft (ubiquitous language, customer cooperation) and hard (design patterns) aspects of DDD can be abused.

Answer (score 5):

You have analysis paralysis, where people analysis and design systems, but never actually build anything.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Shiraz.  Also:

- By following the buzz-words and not following the underlying intent / principles.
- When those doing the DDD don't accept feedback - as the teams overall understanding of the system matures they don't mature with it.
- When the level of detail and the sheer size of the documentation becomes too unwieldly.
- When things that should be re-used aren't - you end up with duplication that makes it harder to maintain a clear model.

Answer (score 0):

Evans own book talks about when it's not appropriate - if you're doing a small one screen application, that won't be extended in the future, then going to the trouble to construct an extensible DDD for that application is polishing the brass on the Titanic.